# Iterate through string of characters and look for int?

Tags: python

I need to iterate through a string with a mixture of letters and numbers. If it finds at least one number, it returns True, else, it returns false. How can I do this?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: `any('0'<=c<='9' for c in s)`

Comment: `set("dfgsdh") & set(string.digits)` or `re.match('[0-9]', input)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a function that returns True when find at least one digit using the `isdigit()` method.

```py
def has_digit(str):
    for letter in str:
        if letter.isdigit():
            return True
    return False

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(has_digit('abcdef'))
    print(has_digit('abd5e'))
```

The output is:

```
False
True
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a function or not as you like. You can also write a ready string or you can use `input` function:

```
x = 'Jack77'

for i in x:
    if i.isdigit():
        print(True)
    else:
        print(False)

#==================

def checking_digits(x):
    for i in x:
        if i.isdigit():
            return True
    return False
print(checking_digits(x))
```

Answer (score -1):

This will create a list of bool values for each character in the string. `isdigit` return `True` if the character is a digit, `False` otherwise. So if any of the bool values (or any the characters is a digit), it will return `True`

```py
has_digits = any(i.isdigit() for i in text)
```